# Email edit prevent duplicates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I'm using the built in authentication in my app and have it set up so a Manager role can create new accounts, assigning a Username and Email. I have edited the RegisterModel inner class of AccountModels to add the regex to ensure an email is a valid email and all works well.

However, when it comes to editing an existing Users Email, I run into trouble. How do I validate that the new email is a valid email? And that another user does not already have this email? I know how to do the regex but where does it go? And I could add a remote call to check for duplicates but again where do I put this stuff? It seems wrong to be checking for duplicates in the controller.

Thanks for your time,

Jay

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
             ... 
             requiresUniqueEmail="true"
             ... />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Comment: Yeah I have that and it does its job on account creation. Problem is, when an existing account is edited it doesn't come into play. So anything can be entered: a non unique email or even a non email. For the time being I am checking the email is unique in the edit action of my controller but need a way to handle this via a model. The edit view is typed to MembershipUser.

Comment: @Jay maybe this post can help you: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/022311-1.aspx